# Can I capture the exception information in python without using try statement?

Tags: python, exception

I wonder if there is a way to capture the exception information when running a Python script, besides using try-except statements?

My Python script is subject to constant change by different people. Errors can occur anywhere inside the file, either a syntax or value error.

I want to be able to interpret the exception information and provide custom error messages to people, for friendly reminding.

I don't want, or couldn't afford, to include all code lines into the try statement. Just wonder if I can have custom error message displayed whenever there is an exception raised.

Thank you for helping out here!

Regards,
Paul

Comment: That's pretty tough. Do you run the script directly? Or could you perhaps call it from a different file? What you want is possible In the latter case

Comment: What would be the alternative to `try`? Having an application with unhandled exceptions? And BTW if someone supplies code with a SyntaxError he has never run it and your development process are not what they should be.

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of a `try`/`catch` statement is that it catches any unhandled exceptions raised by any lower scope.  You can put a `try`/`catch` at the very top level of your script and it'll catch anything that happens anywhere else.  There's no need to wrap each line individually!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        my_main_func()
    except Exception as e:
        # this will catch any exception from anywhere else in the program!
        print(e)
        raise
```